# Find $a$ when $\sin a= \cfrac{3}{5}$ where $0<a<\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ without a calculator

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying to find $a$ when $\sin a= \cfrac{3}{5}$ where $0<a<\cfrac{\pi}{2}$ by using exact values but I can't seem to find a particular method to evaluate it. My original question is this:

Find an expression for $\sin (x+a)$ when $\sin a=\cfrac{3}{5}$ when $a$ is between zero degrees and ninety degrees. And, I think it should be straightforward why I want to evaluate sine at three over five for this question, but, if there is another method, without an evaluation, let me know.

Comment: You don't need actual value of $a$ for that

Comment: what can you use? a calculator? the solution of the equa tion $\sin(a)=\frac{3}{5}$ is not nice

Comment: What form do you seek?  $\sin (x+a)=\frac35 \cos x+\frac 45 \sin x$ is viable.

Comment: or $\sin(x+\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{5})\right)$

Comment: @Dr.MV That is the solution I have in my textbook but I suppose Inwould have to know the value of sine for three over five to find the cosine of $a$. How do I do it otherwise would perhaps be a better question?

Comment: And, I can't use a calculator.

Comment: $\cos a = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 a}=\frac45$ ... without a calculator!

Comment: @Dr.MV I highly doubt that my textbook would be looking for a solution that complicated. The limitations are that we can either use exact values somehow, or some other neat algebraic trick I believe.

Comment: That solution is about as elementary as it gets - not at all complicated.  And as you mentioned, it aligns with the answer in the textbook.  So, again ... what are you seeking here??

Comment: @Dr.MV No part in my textbook mentions about taking square roots to find values of cosine. Is there an article which you can link me to perhaps?

Comment: @uranix Could you clarify?

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity $\sin^2 a+\cos^2 a=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a right-angled triangle of sides $3:4:5$, and mark the angle opposite to the $3$-side as $a$. Then $\sin a = \frac 35$ and $\cos a = \frac 45$.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct and direct answer.